# How to automatically initialize parent field?

Tags: dart

Is it possible to automatically initialize fields from a parent class in the constructor?

I get the syntax error:

Could not match parameter initializer 'this.name' with any field

```dart
class Type {
     String name;  
}

class Language extends Type {
     String id;
     Language(this.name) {
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

While your case is common, at this time the [dart language spec](http://www.dartlang.org/docs/spec/latest/dart-language-specification.html#h.flm5xvbwhs6u) specifically says:

> Executing an initializing formal this.id causes the field id of the immediately surrounding class to be assigned the value of the corresponding actual parameter.

This essentially tells us that `this.variable` notation, in the constructor arguments, will only work on variables in the immediate class and not any parent classes. There are a couple of solutions available: The first is to assign it within the constructor's body:

```dart
class Type {
  String name;
}

class Language extends Type {
  String id;
  Language(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
}
```

Alternatively, if we can change the parent class to have a constructor which will initialize the variable then we can use the initializer list in the child class:

```dart
class Type {
  String name;
  Type();
  Type.withName(this.name);
}

class Language extends Type {
  String id;
  Language(name) : super.withName(name);
}
```

This is assuming there's some reason that the default constructor for `Type` doesn't automatically initialize `name` so we created the 2nd named constructor instead.

Answer (score 0):

first add constructor for parent with `this.propertyName` then use `super.parentPropertyName`

```
abstract class Failure {
  int? code;
  String? message;
  Failure({this.code,this.message});
}

class ServerFailure extends Failure {
  ServerFailure({super.code, super.message});
}
```